# How to secure API from spams & crawling

Tags: api

I am working on  mobile app and its API which uses a private token for every user for authentication.

I want to make sure that no one will misuse the API to crawl my data or to spam my database. Even if I won't publish their posts until they get manual approval, it's still spam and a headache for the data quality guys.

I am using `RoR` and I though about using `Redis` to store a counter for every user and if he reached a specific visits number, I can throttle or block his requests but it will take forever for me to implement the logic and to put a weight for every request and a worker to reset the counters every couple of hours or every day.

Of course I thought about using any ready made tools like `Fail 2 ban` or even `AWS WAF` because I'm running the app on `AWS EB`. But I want to use the `user-id` as identifier and not the `IP` because maybe someone will use `proxies` to crawl or to spam and I think there is a smarter approach instead of this manual one.

Comment: If your potentially already using `redis` there are plenty of packages on npm for rate limiting that you could use in conjunction with server side sessions.